# Finding a point between two planes.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Find a point that is midway between the two parallel planes, $x + 2y - z = -1$ and $3x + 6y - 3z = 4$.

I was able to find that the distance between the two planes is $\frac{7}{3\sqrt{6}}$, but don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Write both planes as $x + 2y - z = ...$. Then your equation should be obvious

Comment: @Shailesh I am still unsure what to do. I understand that there's a normal vector $<1, 2, -1>$, but don't know if that's even helpful/how to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

The first plane can be rewritten as

$$3x+6y-3z=-3$$

The second plane is

$$3x+6y-3z=4$$

Can you write out the equation of the plane that is right in the midway? Can you find one particular point on that plane?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $(1,2,-1)$ is perpendicular to the planes...

So, take a point on one plane,  say $(0,0,1)$, and add half the distance times $(1,2,-1)$...

Get $\frac7{6\sqrt 6}\cdot(1,2,-1)+(0,0,1)=(\frac7{6\sqrt6},\frac7{3\sqrt6},-\frac7{6\sqrt6}+1)$

Comment: What is the logic behind this? Why are you able to just multiply (1, 2, -1) by the distance at which the point should be located?

Comment: @mathhelper  $(1,2,-1)$ is the perpendicular direction

Comment: @mathhelper. It takes some getting used to...  the vector can be thought of as eminating from _any_  point ...